# Export or save custom AutoFormats (Format->AutoFormat...) in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, format

How can I export or save my custom AutoFormat templates those I have created in LibreOffice Calc ?
Full Path: LibreOffice Calc Menu->Format->AutoFormat...

Is there any extension or any files to take a backup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same on Windows and found it in my user directory:

```
LibreOffice/4/user/config/autotbl.fmt
```

Comment: So it's this path in ubuntu.~/.config/libreoffice/3/user/config